# Can I use Threading for dragging and UIButton event simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ipad, animation

I am having a customize user interface for my iPad Application, and There is a dragging of an Object and button event simultaneously. My Problem is that when i drag the object the animation start working and when i leave the object the animation still working for few time. In the mean time while i am trying to press button or dragging another object, its not working till the animation completes.

Comment: the code for the object dragging

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    for (QuestionTile *anotherView in questionViewArray) {
        if ([touch view] == anotherView) {
            NSLog(@" Button Touched ");
            for (TileObject *tileObject in ans_shuffle) {
            }
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            //Method for particular tile
            [self animateuestionTileViewToCenter: anotherView];
            return;
        }
    }
}

Comment: that should be seprate path of execustion so that other UI work when the animation going on

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with the `UIButton` that's animating:
Using (core) animation; you can't interact with the elements during their animation cycle (the regular way).
Only when the animation is finished you can interact with them again.
You can make your own touch handlers on the main view which checks if the touch is 'nearby' the animated button.

If you want to interact with the 'rest':
Make sure you animate your object using the [UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) parameter:

`During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options parameter.`